# How to solve syntax error of d3-array/src/number.js: unknown Statement of type "ForOfStatement"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, d3.js, node-modules

Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

ERROR in ./node_modules/d3-array/src/merge.js

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):

Error: node_modules/d3-array/src/merge.js: unknown Statement of type "ForOfStatement"

```
  for (const array of arrays) {
    yield* array;
  }


export function* numbers(values, valueof) {
  if (valueof === undefined) {
    for (let value of values) {
      if (value != null && (value = +value) >= value) {
        yield value;
      }
    }
  } else {
    let index = -1;
    for (let value of values) {
      if ((value = valueof(value, ++index, values)) != null && (value = +value) >= value) {
        yield value;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to configure Babel to support IE 11. Support was dropped as default by Browserlist but D3 still expects it.

.browswerlistrc

```
defaults
IE 11
```

source: https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/1269#issuecomment-1162311265